# RemoteWebDriver unable to execute Javascript

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver

I'm trying to use Selenium RemoteWebDriver (in C#) with [Multiloginapp](https://multiloginapp.com/automation-selenium-intro/).
Here is my code for initiating a driver:

```
int mlaClientPort = 35000;
Uri driverUrl = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:" + mlaClientPort + "/api/v1/webdriver");

// set desired capabilities to connect to a pre-defined browser profile
DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
dc.SetCapability("multiloginapp-profileId", profileId);

RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(driverUrl, dc);
```

It starts up the browser fine (FireFox).
However, when I attempt to execute Javascript like below:

```
var jsEx = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
object result = jsEx.ExecuteScript("alert('test');");
```

I get the error:

> 'Underlying driver instance does not support executing javascript

This is my first time using RemoteWebDriver but as far as I see, javascript is working in the browser when using it from the console etc.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Your binary version details?

Comment: @DebanjanB I'm using Selenium Webdriver 3.11.2 - downloaded using Nuget Package Manager (latest package as of now).